# Can you run a Neural Network in reverse?

Tags: python, math, encryption, neural-network

Is it possible to get the values of the input layer knowing the output values and the weights and biases in each layer? If yes, how? I was trying to program a symmetrical encryption algorithm using the structure of a neural network.

Comment: You can definitely run a neural network "in reverse". That's how they learn!

Comment: I guess there is a bit more need for rigorousness. The "reverse" mode for learning neural networks is a back-propagation, it calculates gradient of output w.r.t. what you need (usually weights but you can calculate it also w.r.t. input), but in general it does not let you obtain the input values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on size of your inputs, outputs and mostly on your neural network architecture.

Having input [image: x], output [image: y], weights [image: w] and neural network represented as function [image: f] being [image: y=f(x,w)], wanting to obtain [image: x] from [image: w] and [image: y] would mean finding the inverse function of [image: f], let's say [image: f^{-1}].

If the neural network is not injective, you can not find the inverse as there is not unique inverse function [image: f^{-1}] to [image: f].

If your neural network is injective, you need to create an inverse. As neural network is basically a nested function, let's say 3 layer neural network with layers [image: x], [image: a], [image: b], [image: c] thus being [image: f(x,w)=c(b(a(x,w_1),w_2),w_3)] you'd need to create inverse function for [image: a], [image: b], [image: c], and compose them together to have [image: x=f^{-1}(y,w)=a^{-1}(b^{-1}(c^{-1}(y,w_3),w_2),w_1)]. Then it would work and you'd have both [image: f] and [image: f^{-1}].